# Lightning aura components do not have class attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning aura component ui:spinner does not have class attribute. Is there a way to assign a class like using $A.util.addClass(spinner, "hideSpinner"); that would not cause any issues with lifecycle of the component?

Comment: Have you tried using the `toggle` component event? See this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_spinner.htm) for an example. It also looks like the `class` attribute is available as of Spring 2016.

Comment: Toggle and add class with remove class are equivalent. Wonder why there is no class attribute on every ui component.